# Use of \SIlist macro in math mode

Tags: siunitx

Let us consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

text $\phi = \SIlist{10;15;60}{\degree}$; text

text $\phi = \SIlist[list-final-separator={\,\mathrm{and}\,}]{10;15;60}{\degree}$; text

\end{document}
```

Is there a simple way to obtain the last result?

Comment: Did you read the manual about `\SIlist` and related? _This function should be used in text mode._

Comment: @JosephWright Ok. I have read it, now. Anyway, I need to use the `\SIlist` macro in a context as I wrote in MWE. I believe it is more logical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Joseph wrote, `\SIlist` has to be in text mode.  So either you do:

```
text $\phi =$ \SIlist{10;15;60}{\degree}; text
```

or you use `\usepackage{amsmath}` and

```
text $\phi = \text{\SIlist{10;15;60}{\degree}}$; text
```

The second option is preferable, since it also works in math displays or when the formula continues after the list.

Comment: Both the options work, but the latter is more "clean" than the former. My upvote.